# Neo4j: Relating a node to a specific node with the same name

Tags: neo4j, graphql, grandstack

I have a list of all of the US states and towns. States can have the same town names so I'm checking to make sure each town is connected to their respected state.

I have events connected to a town, but the problem is that my events are connecting to multiple towns in different states. How can I connect my new event to a town within a certain state? 
This is my schema.

```
type State {
  stateName: String!
  stateAbbreviation: String!
  towns: [Town] @relation(name: "STATE_OUT", direction: "OUT")
}

type Town {
  state: String!
  name: String!
  events: [CraftShowEvent]
}

type Event {
  name: String!
  day: String!
  month: String!
  time: String!
  town: String!
  state: String!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are creating the graph database, make sure you have this data model between `"Town"` node and `"Event"` node

```
EVENT -> [] -> Town
WHERE 
  EVENT.town = Town.Name 
AND
  EVENT.state = Town.state
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to update my question in case anyone else ran into this. I was using neo4j and graphql which automatically generate the queries and mutations based on my graphql schema.

Instead I made modifications and used the @cypher directive. I needed more control of how my data was saved.

```
type Mutation {
  setBatchTown(listOfTowns: [BatchTown]): Town
    @cypher(statement:"""
      UNWIND $listOfTowns AS el
      MERGE (t:Town {name: el.name, state: el.state})
      WITH t
      MATCH (s:State)
      WHERE t.state = s.name
      CREATE (t)-[:STATE_OUT]->(s)
    """)

  setEvent(event: InputEvent): Event
    @cypher(statement:"""
      MERGE (e:Event { name: $event.name, day: $event.day, month: $event.month, time: $event.time, town: $event.town, state: $event.state })
      WITH e
      MATCH (s:State), (t:Town {name: e.town, state: e.state})
      WHERE e.state = s.name AND e.town = t.name
      MERGE (e)-[:TOWN_OF]->(t)
      RETURN t
    """)
 }
```

Then when I make a request I could do something like this.

```
        client.mutate({ variables: { 
            listOfTowns: [{
              name: 'town1'
              state: 'VA'
            },
            {
              name: 'town2'
              state: 'WA'
            }] 
        }, mutation: CREATE_STATE_MUTATION })
          .then(() => resolve())
          .catch(err => reject(err))
        })
```